# PDF HTTP GET request with digest and Safari

Tags: jquery, authentication, safari, get, digest

I'm facing some problems with authentication. I'm developing an application for Samsung SmartTV (is based on Safari) and I want to use iframe tag to open a PDF file. To view the PDF, you need to be logged in to the server, which only supports Digest Authentication. The problem is when I ask for it with 
    (iframe src="'+link+'" height="600" width="800")
it sends basic authentication. Is there a way to set the authentication to Digest? If accessing from safari web brower, a popup with requesting for username and password shows up. With Firefox and other browsers work good because they send the digest authentication preemptively.

If it's not possible, I'm able to get the pdf file using $.ajax, but don't know how to display a pdf from xmlhttprequest.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance!!